# TensorFlow.js Stateful SimpleRNN Tensor is disposed

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm Trying to create a stateful RNN model. I can call predict once, then the other calls give me an error: `Uncaught Error: Tensor is disposed.`

[predict error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsUtw.png)

My model is declared as follows:

```py
function createModel() {
  const inputGame = tf.input({
    batchShape: [1, 1, OUTPUT_SHAPE],
    name: 'inputGame',
  });
  const inputPlayer = tf.input({
    batchShape: [1, 1, INPUT_PLAYER],
    name: 'inputPlayer',
  });
  const input = tf.layers
    .concatenate({name: 'concatenate'})
    .apply([inputGame, inputPlayer]);
  const rnn = tf.layers.simpleRNN({
    units: 128,
    activation: 'relu',
    stateful: true,
    kernelInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
    biasInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
    name: 'rnn',
  });
  const dense = tf.layers.dense({
    units: OUTPUT_SHAPE,
    activation: 'sigmoid',
    kernelInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
    biasInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
    name: 'dense',
  });
  const output = dense.apply(rnn.apply(input));
  const model = tf.model({inputs: [inputGame, inputPlayer], outputs: [output]});
  const surface = {name: 'Model Summary', tab: 'Model Inspection'};
  tfvis.show.modelSummary(surface, model);
  return model;
}
```

Then I call predict every second:

```py
const inputGameTensor = tf.tensor(frame);
const inputPlayerTensor = tf.zeros([1, 1, INPUT_PLAYER]);
const output = model.predict([inputGameTensor, inputPlayerTensor], true);
```

I suspect that there is a `state` tensor inside the `SimpleRNN` layer and it is `disposed()` after calling predict once. I don't know TensorFlow.js well enough to investigate this hypothesis.

I have the code running at:
https://luxedo.github.io/TGNN/

Comment: Can you please do a working snippet that is throwing the error on https://stackblitz.com ? It will be easier to spot the error and to help.

Comment: I coudn't make it work there. Instead I used gh-pages